# Which plants will grow well in 18-24 inch (height) x 12-14 inch (diameter) pots?

Tags: plant-recommendations

I need to place pots in a flower bed in my balcony, which is about 18 inches deep and 15 inches wide. I'm planning to buy a few tall planters which will be 18-24 inches in height and about 12-14 inches in diameter.

In a place like Goa, India (tropical/beach/seaside climate), what kind of plants will grow tall & bushy in such tall planters?

Answer (score 2):

Since plants are living things, once set out in your pots they will continue to grow and eventually will need to be replaced, so you don't want tree type material which will be a pain to replace. So we are thinking annuals. One important criterion is whether you are planting for your own benefit or as entertainment for passers by - in the latter case you are probably after colour, and in the former you can consider less showy but more productive plants.

For flowers you can consider the usual stuff like petunias and geraniums, but these tend to be disorderly in growth and need some pruning attention as they grow, which is not really a hardship as the growth is soft.

For your own entertainment, peppers (sweet, hot) are hard to beat. They produce a tallish plant with a good solid stem which holds up in windy conditions and rarely needs pruning; flowers are inconspicuous compared to other plants but the fruits could supply you with a constant flow of product, either vegetable or spices, for the kitchen. There are many different varieties available, they are easily grown from seed, and very simple to replace once they become too old to be attractive.

Here is an example of a pepper in a 10" pot. Not grown by me, but the photo is mine. The tomato cage is not really necessary, but this pot gets moved around a bit so it helps with security. The variety is "aji limon":

[image: Aji limon]

Answer (score 0):

Mandevilla is a tropical, flowering plant that could be a good fit for your needs. I plant it as an annual in my climate (Northeast US), but I think in warmer, more tropical places, it will return year over year.

It is a climbing plant, so if you have a trellis or balcony wall, it will grow upward and give you the height you are looking for. According to [GardeningKnowHow](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/vines/mandevilla/mandevilla-plant.htm), if you pinch it, it will also get bushier.

> This method of pruning your mandevilla will create a bushier and fuller plant. To pinch your mandevilla vine, simply use your fingers to pinch off 1/4 to 1/2 inch (6 mm. to 1 cm.) off the end of each stem.

I think it's a really pretty plant that could give you both the height and bushiness you're looking for.
[image: red flowering plant in pot]

Photo is from [HGTV](https://www.hgtv.com/outdoors/flowers-and-plants/groundcover-and-vines/mandevilla-plant-care).